# Can I use "reinstate" in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am developing a program, which splits data into small messages. I send these messages one by one to another program in a random order. The other program can restore the original order of the messages.

Can I use `reinstate the order` or only `restore` is an appropriate word in this context?

Comment: You can *reorder* the messages into their original order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use *to restore the order* in that case if you want to mean "to put it back to the original order".

[Reinstate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinstate) is more broadly used in a job or position as defined in Merriam-Webster:

> to put (someone) back in a job or position that had been taken away
>
> to begin using or dealing with (a law, policy, system, etc.) again

[Restore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restore) has a closer meaning in:

> *to return (something) to an earlier or original condition* by repairing it, cleaning it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the suffix "re-" generally means - to do again

reinstate -  to instate, or appoint, him to the possition again

restore, however, breaks it a bit by meaning to take back to a previois state according to it's history.

what you're looking for is more of a reassembly so you'll want to use reassemble